# Issue with code markdown in comments

Tags: bug, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backslash escaped with backticks rendered incorrectly in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11388/backslash-escaped-with-backticks-rendered-incorrectly-in-comments)
>   [Backslash escaping in code regions in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74340/backslash-escaping-in-code-regions-in-comments)

When trying to add a `\` at the end in a code block in a comment it breaks the code block.

I've also tried to fool it by adding two `\`s to no avail.

Comment: `\` <- single slash in code block

Comment: ``\`` This should work (two backticks on either side of the backslash)

Comment: Backslash: `\​`

Comment: `yay! .....\` ??

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa: Sorry, I forgot to add the explanation. I inserted the unicode character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (`U+200B`) after the backslash.

Comment: See [this answer of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79981/115866) regarding code spans in comments. @murgatroid99 is correct; the right way to do this is using two (or more) backticks on either side.

Comment: @balpha tnx for the reference. Feel free to delete this dupe if you feel like it :-)