# \\ while typed in comments

Tags: discussion, comments, markdown-rendering, character-escaping

I see that when I type a double backslash (`\\`) in a comment on Stack Overflow, it prints only a single `\`, escaping the `\` character. Is escaping this character necessary in the comments section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because the backslash is used for escaping markdown (for example, when you want a literal backtick.

For example:

`code` , but `code`

is

```
 `code` , but \`code\`
```

in MarkDown. Letting you escape the backslash lets you say that "this is not an escape character"

Comment: When I type double backslash \\ it shows me both.

Comment: @hims056: hmm, strange. It seems to show only one in a post

Comment: Yea, you are right, but is that required in comments section. if it is an answer, that is required but why in comments.

Comment: @sibi sure, you always need an escape char. This is a programming site, comments may have code as well. You need to be able to accurately type it.

Comment: @Manishearth But I will not be able to highlight the code in comments as I would be able to do in an answer.  And the comments in SO , I thought its similar to /* */  in C.

Comment: @sibi what? You can highlight code, like 'abcabc`

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across this behaviour in an AskUbuntu Q&A, and it baffled me. With this input:

```
The `\` character escapes the `.` character.
```

the output in an "answer" is:

> The `\` character escapes the `.` character.

Which is just what you would expect. But the behaviour **changes** (inexplicably, imo) in the **comment** area. I will comment this answer with that text as demonstration, once [just as given](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163362/while-typed-in-comments/258886#comment843766_258886), and then again with the [backslash itself escaped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163362/while-typed-in-comments/258886#comment843774_258886) -- neither one produces an "expected" result.

It would be good for there to be consistency here!

Comment: And the demonstration using the same input as above ... | The `\` character escapes the `.` character. | ... which doesn't match the rendering in the "answer" area!

Comment: The `\ ` character escapes the `.` character. Uses \`\ `

Comment: @DavidPostill - Yes, but the point is rather the inconsistency of the Markdown rendering between the "answer" and "comment" areas. I know the comment area uses "mini-Markdown formatting" (see the "help" text beside the comment box when adding a comment) but the markdown available should at least (one would think) be consistent.

Comment: Would be interesting to know what insights @balpha would have on this.

Comment: And, for the record, here's that input string with a double-backslash, which ought to escape the escape (as it were): The `\\` character escapes the `.` character. | So nope, that's not right either.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that. I couldn't work out how to escape correctly :( I don't know of any workaround other than the extra space (which of course also doesn't display correctly).

Comment: [Backslash escaped with backticks rendered incorrectly in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11388)

Comment: See [Backslash in ticks in comments](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/503). "Backslash escaping in inline code in comments is disabled, except for a backtick ` within single backticks". Use \`\`\\`\` to display ``\``