# How do I format a backslash as code with backticks in comments?

Tags: support, comments, markdown, code-formatting

I'm trying to write a single backslash in a comment as code formatted by backtick. Like this:

```
`\`
```

but it escapes the backtick and doesn't close the "inline code block".

I've read [Backslash escaped with backticks rendered incorrectly in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11388/backslash-escaped-with-backticks-rendered-incorrectly-in-comments) but couldn't figure out.

How do I format a single backslash in comment as code?

Comment: Seems like the answer is to add a trailing space, or just don't do use code (I question whether it really needs to be formatted differently). It's one of the markdown edge cases where it can't decide whether `\ ` is code or an escape character.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using 2 backticks seems to work

```
``\``
```

BTW if you want to escape a backtick use

```
`\``
```

Comment: escaped backshlash ``\`` and escaped backtick `\``

Comment: Let's ``\`` try it. *edit* wow! it works! :D

Comment: ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 7):

**``` ``\`` ``` → `\` : to format a single backslash as `` `code` `` in comments, enclose it in *double backticks*.**

Same for the more general case of a `\` at the end of a `` `code` `` section:
Comment source ``` ``C:\Windows\`` ``` renders to `C:\Windows\`.

A backslash at any position other than the end works fine between `` `single backticks` ``. (As well as ``` ``double ones`` ```.)

**(**`\` is not treated as special in comment `` `code` `` sections, except when followed by a backtick while enclosed by single backticks:
Comment source `` `…\`…` `` renders to `` …`… ``.
But ``` ``…\`…`` ``` renders to `` …\`… ``.

If you need both a trailing backslash `\` and any number of backticks `` ` `` at the beginning, you can go dirty **hack** and separate the content backticks from the surrounding backticks with an **invisible Unicode character**, like [*zero width space*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm): You can copy it from between the arrows: →​← (It's invisible, but it's there, I promise! ;)  To get a hold of it, copy the arrows along with it, then delete them after pasting.)

(If you need both a trailing backslash `\` and an occurrence of a double backtick ``` `` ``` in the interior of your `` `code` `` section, you can enclose it in triple backticks ```` ```…``` ```` and so on.)
**)**

<sub>Credits: This post was helped by *juergen d*'s [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201663/how-do-i-format-a-backslash-as-code-with-backticks-in-comments/201665#201665) and *ThisSuitIsBlackNot*'s [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11388/backslash-escaped-with-backticks-rendered-incorrectly-in-comments#comment794018_11388) (on a similar question) - thanks!</sub>