# Code formatting broke in this comment

Tags: bug, comments, code-formatting

I did a bit of research, but I don't think this has been asked elsewhere.

I added a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40282629/3795597), and the formatting broke. The "code" part consisted of multiple backslashes: `\`  -> `\\\`, `\\`.

Interestingly, the formatting doesn't seem to be broken in the questions/answers. There is a comment right below this question to show the issue.

This is another example of why we need preview for comments.

Comment: Here is the offending part again `\`  -> `\\\`, `\\`

Comment: Backslashes are used as escape characters, but code blocks (in posts) seem to be an exception. Apparently, this behaviour is not enabled in comments.

Comment: Related [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74340/backslash-escaping-in-code-regions-in-comments?rq=1) which has [status-completed]. Apparently, the bug reappeared. Or I'm missing something...

Comment: Thanks, I did not find that answer before. That could be related to the fact that `\\`` is considered as an escaped backtick. If so, `\\` -> `\\\\`, `\\\` Should render correctly, I think (edit: does not seem to be the case). It remains that it is inconsistent with the way code blocks are parsed in questions/answers

Comment: The backslash is escaping your backticks... double backticks should work ``\``  -> ``\\\``,  ``\\``

Comment: @Cai is correct, and such answer is given in the dupe.

Comment: While not exactly a duplicate, this is correct. I will mark it as a duplicate in a few minutes. I would also like to see an "official" answer to this difference in behavior. BTW, ti seems that it also causes problems with a space: `` ` \ ` -> ` \\\ `, ` \\ ` ``  gets rendered as ` \ ` -> ` \\\ `, ` \\ ` (and it can't figure how to render the first part properly either).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslash is escaping your backticks, so the code formatting isn't ending where you expect it to. You can use double backticks instead. So instead of:

> ```
> `\`  -> `\\\`, [...] `\\`
> ```

You want this:

> ```
> ``\``  -> ``\\\``, [...] ``\\``
> ```

For more information see [How do I format a backslash as code with backticks in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201663/how-do-i-format-a-backslash-as-code-with-backticks-in-comments) and [How do I escape a backtick in Markdown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82718/307988)

Comment: Thanks. I would have rather seen a double backslash to cancel the backslash behavior; which seems pretty standard (at the very least in the context of this comment). Any words on why the behavior isn't the same as in the regular posts? `\\`` doesn't seem to escape backticks there. And, as a matter of fact, double backticks don't seem to work in comments.

Comment: Honestly no idea why the behaviour is different! I would think escaping the backslash with a double backslash would make more sense too but seems it doesn't work, all I know is that double backticks work :)

Comment: Double backticks definitely work in comments though (``\``  -> ``\\\``, ``\\``)

Comment: Sorry, I meant posts. Q/A :)