# Inconsistent escaping of backslash+backtick characters

Tags: bug, comments, code-formatting

When I type the following code:

> backtick backslash backslash backtick

In a question or answer, it is interpreted as: `\\`.

However, in comments, the second backslash escapes the second backtick, which turns the rest of the comment into code-formatted text. See example comment below this question.

I see this question [Backslash escaped with backticks rendered incorrectly in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11388) as a possible duplicate (marked as status-bydesign), but this specific scenario does not seem to be covered.

---

NOTE: The behavior on MetaSE seems to be different from that on SO. On SO, the rest of the comment turns into pre-formatted text. On MetaSE, one backslash disappear instead.

Comment: Demo comment: Typing `\\` turns the rest into code-formatted text.

Comment: Yes, this is a known issue, comment escaping is inconsistent with post escaping rules.