# Can't put backslash into backticks in chat

Tags: discussion, support, bug, chat, markdown

I have recently found in chat that you cannot put backslashes in backticks without them showing and it disappearing:

[image]

Why is this so? If you put another letter in with it though it works as would be expected. So is this a bug or some sort of odd intentional feature?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11388/260841 -- it's about comments but applies to chat as well

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/can-we-please-have-a-place-where-changes-to-the-markdown-syntax-are-documented/79981#79981 for some info and for a way to make it work (use multiple backticks as delimiters).